# Setting a label to a file with AppleScript

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, label

I'm trying to put a colored label on a file with AppleScript using the following code:

```
set theFile to "HDD:Path:to:the:file.ext"

tell application "Finder"
    set label of file theFile to 3
end tell
```

but when I run it in a terminal with `osascript theScript.scpt` I get the following error:

> theScript.scpt:144:178: execution error: Finder got an error: Can't set label of document file "file.ext" of folder "the
>   " of folder "to" of folder "Path" of startup disk to 3. (-10006)

Any ideas why I'm having an issue and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be coded as a `label index` not a `label` and it needs to be an `alias`:

```
set theFile to "HDD:Path:to:the:file.ext" as alias
tell application "Finder" to set label index of theFile to 3
```

Comment: Can anyone give an update on whether this is still the correct way to do this? Ever since upgrading to High Sierra, when I try to do this I get the following error: `execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set label index of file "Foo:Bar:SomeFile" to 3. (-10006)`

Comment: check the naming of your Hard Drive!