# Setting a custom label to a file with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder

Here's what I got, but I ave a custom label with "Active Projects".
How do I assign?

tell application "Finder" to set label index of theFile to 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a label to a file with AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250691/setting-a-label-to-a-file-with-applescript)

Comment: What version of OS X/macOs are you using and is a _tag_ or  _label_?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with vanilla AppleScript. The Finder dictionary does not support adding tags.

However you can do it with AppleScriptObjC which gives access to the Foundation framework

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

use framework "Foundation"

on addTagToPath(theTag, thePath)
    set theURL to current application's NSURL's fileURLWithPath:thePath
    set {success, tagArray, theError} to theURL's getResourceValue:(reference) forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(reference)
    if theError is not missing value then error theError's localizedDescription() as text
    if tagArray is not missing value and (tagArray's containsObject:theTag) as boolean is true then return
    if tagArray is missing value then set tagArray to current application's NSMutableArray's array()
    tagArray's addObject:theTag
    set {success, theError} to theURL's setResourceValue:tagArray forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(reference)
    if theError is not missing value then error theError's localizedDescription() as text
end addTagToPath
```

and use it

```
try
    addTagToPath("MyTag", "/Users/myUser/path/to/file.ext")
on error e
    log e
end try
```

The `try` block catches errors thrown by the `NSURL` methods

Comment: Thanks! I get Expected “end” but found “on”.

Comment: Which OS X version are you using? And in which line does the error occur?

Comment: My bad, Fixed! Thanks so much!!!